# Unsure on errors exporting MS SQL 2008 table to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have joined together a few tables in my database and I'm not trying to export that joined table to an Excel spreadsheet to be imported into another DB. However its throwing me an error I don't understand (my knowledge of SQL is limited)

Here is the error:

```
Copying to `RDBMissingCandidates` (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Spreadsheet is full.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - RDBMissingCandidates.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - RDBMissingCandidates.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - RDBMissingCandidates" (76) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (87). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - RDBMissingCandidates returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: You should remove the jpg file - there is personal data there. Provide just list of columns (and types), amount of rows returned by your query.
You can also check whether copying query results into excel "by hand" is possible.

Comment: How many records are returned? If it is more than the limit of what excel can hold then it might fail.

Comment: Image removed, I think its down to the date format, I have a feeling I have something older than 1900 for some reason which is causing this error with my version

Answer (score 1):

The problem was down to the amount of data trying to be exported to excel. It was to much for it to handle. I wrote a query which exported the rows in chunks of 10,000. I now have achieved was I set out too.